# SDI-12 voltage translator buffer

Tags: buffer, interface

I want to implement an SDI-12 interface and I found [this schematic](https://www.daycounter.com/Circuits/SDI-12/SDI-12-Interface.phtml) online. The author says that the buffer translates the 3.3V voltage from the microcontroller to 5V for the SDI-12 line.

However, the buffer is [SN74LCV1G240](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g240.pdf?ts=1600270674247&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.ro%252F) which has the high-level input voltage (Vih) of 0.7 x Vcc, which is 3.5V at Vcc = 5V.

So it seems that it will not work as the author says. Am I right or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely correct.

LVC is a wrong type to convert a 3.3V signal to 5V signal.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Can you recommend me an adequate buffer? (If possible, with 2 inputs/outputs, non-inverted enable and low power)

Comment: Unfortunately shopping questions what to buy are off topic. You can find a suitable part yourself by going to parametric search of logic chips on almost any logic chip manufacturer webpage, and specifying the search filters according to the gate function and gate count.